# How to run Selenium without referencing localhost?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, networking, selenium-chromedriver, localhost

I am running Selenium for Python behind a proxy on Windows. I am getting the error
`Your requested host "localhost" could not be resolved by DNS.`

This is an intractable problem. I cannot use a hosts file because it is bypassed. I have added localhost to the excluded URLs for the internet. But everything has to go through the proxy, there is no bypassing it. The problem arises because something in Selenium is calling localhost. This address goes out to the proxy and the proxy is returning an error, as if to say "localhost, that isn't an IP address that I know!",and returns the error.
I don't know if there is a way to change the DNS but that would require an institutional change (our organization is very large).

Why is the localhost reference necessary at all? Is there a way to run Selenium without booting a webserver that calls localhost?

Comment: This sounds like you should open a ticket directly with the Selenium project: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues (Without more info, such as what language binding you're using or where that issue happens, it will be tricky to debug.)

Comment: The webdriver will run on localhost to send/receive commands to the browser.  (wire protocol)  I suppose one way around that is to send commands to a remote grid.